# Replicate cv::warpAffine in Swift with Core Image

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, core-image

I am trying to replicate a face alignment algorithm purely in Swift with Core Image. However, I am already failing at trying to replicate a simple warpAffine from opencv in Swift

Python code:

```
print(M) #M is a matrix calculated using some face detection code
print("let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: {0[0][0]}, b: {0[1][0]}, c: {0[0][1]}, d: {0[1][1]}, tx: {0[0][2]}, ty: {0[1][2]})".format(M))
warped = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(image_size[1],image_size[0]), borderValue = 0.0) #warped is the correctly aligned image, image_size is 112,112
```

My swift version:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

let ctx = CIContext()
let image = UIImage(named: "lg.jpg")
let ciimage = CIImage(image: image!)
let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 0.390825773796, b: -0.0333640808264, c: 0.0333640808264, d: 0.390825773796, tx: -53.8777275485, ty: -23.0859985227)
let aligned = ciimage?.transformed(by: transform)
let size = aligned!.extent
let center = CGPoint(x: size.midX, y: size.midY)
let cropRect = CGRect(x: center.x-56, y: center.y-56, width: 112, height: 112)
let cropped = aligned!.cropped(to: cropRect)
```

The image given by the swift version (`cropped`) is rotated by a few degrees to the left and the crop is too far down.

I already tried reordering the transform parameters, as I am guessing there is where I went wrong. But according to the [opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine) and the [CGAffineTransform docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) the parameters should be correct.

Comment: What `CIFilter` are you using? It's not in your code, and I'm rather unsure why you've tagged it as [core-image]. If it's because you can call certain things on a `CIImage`... why? If you aren't using a filter or a kernel - which I'm thinking you might - then why not just use an *actual* image (be it `UIImage` or `CGImage`)?

Comment: @dfd Because this will actually be implemented in a chain of CoreML requests. Since CoreML likes CVPixelBuffers, I don't want to convert that to a UIImage first, to save overhead. I just used a UIImage here to test the alignment in a playground first.

Comment: Good reason, I think. So if Core Image has `CIDetection` (pre-iOS 11) and CoreML and Vision, what specifically - code-wise - are you doing?

Comment: @dfd Don't really understand your question, but the idea is to do offline face recognition (So pre-iOS 11 won't work). I have done this before, but the face alignment was done using OpenCV in Objective-C. I want to rewrite that part in pure Swift for performance and ease of compiling reasons. However, I already got stuck on just performing the same affine transform as the face alignment is doing in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately, I was unable to replicate it using CoreImage. I did get it to work nicely with a UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {
    func transformed(by transform: CGAffineTransform, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let orig = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        c?.concatenate(transform)
        self.draw(in: orig)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result!
    }
}
```

While this does work, converting from CIImage to UIImage and back, proves to be too slow for my use case.